# Rspec for object.reload.changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a job to send notifications and inside it there is a condition not to send it if the object has changed, `object.reload.changed?`. How do I write proper spec for this?

```
it 'doesn\'t send notification if fields have changed' do
      expect(Parse).
        not_to receive(:send_notification).with(
          user_id,
          message
        )
      object.update(status: :new_status) # it updates the object before executing the job, so doesn't make too much sense...
      Job.perform
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. `object.reload.changed?` would always return `false`, because `object.reload` reloads the object from the database and therefore it resets all unsaved changes on the object.

Comment: @spickermann I need to check if the object hasn't changed its status before sending a notification, because notification messages depend on statuses. So I reload the object to check if it still has the same status.